# Python and json, How to print data["key"]

Tags: python, json, key, web-scraping

I have a simple scraping code:

```
import urllib
import re
import json

htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://dx.com/p/GetProductInfoRealTime?skus=48616")

htmltext = json.load(htmltext)

print htmltext
```

It outputs:

```
{u'data': [{u'sku': 48616, u'isShowDiscount': False, u'currencycode': u'USD', u'issoldout': False, u'adddate': u'10/28/2010', u'discount': 0, u'currencysymbol': u'US$', u'price': u'4.20', u'listprice': u''}], u'success': True}
```

I can not figure out how to get the data in the correct format so I can use the terms on the left side of the colons as the key for the terms on the right side.

I would like to

```
print htmltext["sku"] 
48616
```

or

```
print htmltext["price"]
4.20
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: try `htmltext['data'][0]['price']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is a dictionary with the key `data`,

So access the inner list with:

```
htmltext[u"data"]
```

Then to access `"sku"`, you need to access the dictionary within the list in `"data"`'s value.

```
inner_dict = htmltext[u"data"][0]

print(inner_dict[u"sku"])
```

You could define a function such as:

```
def get_data(dict_index, key):
        return htmltext[u"data"][dict_index][key]

print(get_data(0, u"sku"))
```

Comment: The function works perfectly, I am confused on the "u" though. Will there always be a "u" when I am using json in this way?

Comment: @Travis: The `u` just means it's a Unicode string. It's not part of the string itself, any more than the quotes are.

Comment: agreed with abarnert, just to clarify, I put the `u` in to keep consistency. It is not strictly necessary.

Comment: The `u` may not be strictly necessary in Python 2, but it is in Python 3. (Python 2 is overly lax, letting you mix bytestrings with Unicode strings.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
def get_data(htmltext, sub_key, key='data', indx=0):
    return htmltext[key][indx][sub_key]

print get_data(htmltext, 'sku')
```

Check the use of default arguments.

Cheers!